# why npm vue-google-login is not showing on Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm try to make google login sample project with Vue.
First I found npm package named 'vue-google-login' is very nice.
So I try to use it but components which import from 'vue-google-login' seems not working(Button is not showing).
I am following 'vue-google-login' npm guide with code below. And I got link at last.

```
<template>
  <div id="google">
    <GoogleLogin :params="params" :renderParams="renderParams"></GoogleLogin>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GoogleLogin from 'vue-google-login'

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    // Google
    params: {
      client_id: "cliend_id"
    },
    renderParams: {
      width: 250,
      height: 50,
      longtitle: true
    }
  }),
  components: {
    GoogleLogin
  }
};
</script>
```

'vue-google-login' npm : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-login

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '_c' of undefined.....
Really don't know what is _c...

Comment: @Kioni Refer the medium article. Hopefully it will helps you https://medium.com/@jebasuthan/signup-with-google-using-vuejs-11c9d4428250

Comment: @Jebasuthan Thanks for the link. But I really want to know what is happening on my project so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vue-google-login` is [built for Vue 2](https://github.com/rmartide/vue-google-login/blob/98d9d46/package.json#L51), but your [project uses Vue 3](https://github.com/khndhkx123/test/blob/fa4a6b0/google/package.json#L12), which is not compatible.

One option is to downgrade Vue to version 2. Or you could use a different Google auth library that supports Vue 3, such as [`vue3-google-oauth2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-google-oauth2).

Answer (score 0):

Since you uses Vue3 try [vue3-google-login](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/), this is a lightweight plugin for implementing log-in and sign-up flows using [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web) with the help of Google [3P Authorization JavaScript Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/load-3p-authorization-library), this can also helps to enable features like One-Tap Login and Automatic Login features

Answer (score 0):

We have created a library called [vue3-google-signin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-google-signin) to achieve this task quickly with Vue3 using the latest Google 3P Authorization Library.
This library includes a set of composables and components to help your case.

If you are using Nuxt3, use this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-vue3-google-signin) we created

To add the google sign-in button use the following snippet.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  GoogleSignInButton,
  type CredentialResponse,
} from "vue3-google-signin";

// handle success event
const handleLoginSuccess = (response: CredentialResponse) => {
  const { credential } = response;
  console.log("Access Token", credential);
};

// handle an error event
const handleLoginError = () => {
  console.error("Login failed");
};
</script>

<template>
  <GoogleSignInButton
    @success="handleLoginSuccess"
    @error="handleLoginError"
  ></GoogleSignInButton>
</template>
```

You can read docs [here](https://vue3-google-signin.syetalabs.io/)

Disclaimer: Im the author of this library